# Jquery animate doesn't work in mobile but jquery css does, why?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-animate

I'm fine tuning mobile on a site I'm working on. However, I'm getting a strange animate issue in jquery. This works:

```
$('.'+myElement).css({'height':topParentH+'px','width':topParentW+'px'});
```

However, this does not:

```
$('.'+myElement).animate({'height':topParentH+'px','width':topParentW+'px'});
```

both are triggered on a "click" (in this case touch).

I'm using chrome on my nexus 7 for testing right now, so this is a webkit based browser on mobile.

----- edit -----

Could this just be because I'm using a new OS (Android 4.2) and a beta browser? I tested it on a kindle fire (the only other Android based tablet I could get my hands on right now) and it worked fine.